# How to route to Controller Index Action Method using Angular JS Routing on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am having cancel button. When i clicked it i want to route to Index Action method of Student Controller.

How can i do that

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel" ng-click="Cancel()" />
```

My MVC Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller
{

    // GET: Test
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it spa or you want to navigate between c# MVC route?

Comment: It's not spa, i want to navigate between C# mvc route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are just directly wanting to go to an MVC route - If you wanted to do it directly in the View you could use:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("Index", "Student") + "'");" />
```

Or from your Angular controller:

```
$scope.Cancel = function() {
    window.location = "/Student/Index";
};
```